# Leer TXT desde PHP con parrafos en vez de lineas

Tags: php

Tengo un problemita y no le encuentro la vuelta.

Aqui seguramente alguien me podrá decir para donde encaro:

Resulta que tengo un .txt (Archivo de Texto Plano) con el siguiente contenido:

```
laps=0
flag=Green
flagimg=C:\Users\marklubi\Desktop\AppBackgrounds\bg_active_1@2x.jpg

pos1fname=William
pos1lname=Prince
pos1num=48
pos1time=17.883
pos1laps=5
pos1blap=3
pos1btime=15.969
pos1diff=

pos2fname=Colby
pos2lname=Horner
pos2num=15
pos2time=17.980
pos2laps=5
pos2blap=3
pos2btime=15.968
pos2diff=0.229

pos3fname=Ethan
pos3lname=Endicott
pos3num=00
pos3time=17.054
pos3laps=4
pos3blap=3
pos3btime=16.062
pos3diff=1.429

leaderfname=WILLIAM
leaderlname=PRINCE
leadernum=48
leaderblap=3
leaderbtime=15.969

fastestfname=CAMERON
fastestlname=YOUNG
fastestnum=34
fastestblap=3
fastestbtime=15.864
```

Pretendo leerlo desde PHP y luego con el generar un xml, o mostrarlo, lo que sea.

Se como hacerlo con file() y luego separar los campos. Pero como se podria hacer para este caso, donde no estan linea por linea, sino que digamos, en "parrafos".

El primero es unico. Los siguientes se repiten (entre 1 y 40 pueden ser) y los dos ultimos son tambien unicos.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como encarar esto-?

Desde ya, agradezco al que pueda aportar una idea.

Comment: Esa es la estructura??... Si estás procesando todo el texto del archivo en 1 variable, separá cuando haya 2 saltos de línea consecutivos!! ... Si vas línea por línea, sería lo mismo que cuando encuentres una línea en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes abrir el archivo e iterarlo linea a linea. Luego por el nombre del campo sabes que inicia la linea y termina la linea (para el bloque), y lo procesas como lo necesitas.

Ejemplo el primer bloque inicia en  "pos" . $i . "fname" y cierra en "pos" . $i . "diff".

Aqui te anexo un código que te puede guiar

$html = file_get_contents($url);
        $html = fix($html);

```
    $fileName = fileSave("bienes", $html);

    $file = fopen($fileName, "r");

    $htmlTable = "";
    $switch = 0;
    $tipo = 0;

    while (($line_detail = fgets($file)) !== false) {

        if (strpos($line_detail, "detalleSubasta.php") !== FALSE) {
            if (strpos($line_detail, 'Bienes') !== FALSE) {
                $tipo = 1;  
            }

            if (strpos($line_detail, 'Lotes') !== FALSE) {
                $tipo = 2;
            }
        }

        $pos = strpos($line_detail, 'datosSubastas');

        if ($pos !== FALSE) {
            /* Bien o Lote */
            $switch = 1;                                
        }

        if ($switch == 1) {
            $htmlTable .= $line_detail;
        }

        $pos = strpos($line_detail, '/table');
        if ($pos !== FALSE) {
            $switch = 0;                                
        }

    }

    $htmlTable = "<html>" . $htmlTable . "</html>";
```

Saludos,

Comment: Encontrado!sd asd

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado el principio de la solucion! Gracias Jorge Londoño!

He filtrado y eliminado la fila 1 (banderas) y las ultimas que no son posiciones. (Luego debo volver a encontrarlas para agregarlas junto con las otras fuera del loop de las posiciones). Ahora debo agregarlas a un xml, pero es facil y conocido.

Asi quedo el codigo:

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('data.txt');
$data  = preg_split("[\n\r]", $string);
foreach($data as $posicion=>$lineasdecampo)
{
if ($posicion == 0 || strpos($lineasdecampo, 'leader') || strpos($lineasdecampo, 'fastest')){ }else{        
    echo "<hr>Renglon " . $posicion ."<br>";
    $data  = preg_split("[\n\r]", $string);
    $datos = explode("\r", trim($lineasdecampo));
$mdatar = "";   
foreach($datos as $posicionx=>$datax)
    {
    $datofila = explode("=", $datax);   
    $mdatar .= $datofila[1].",";
    }   
echo $mdatar."<br>";
}   
}
?>
```

Saludos!

Comment: excelente trabajo, saludos